# Mount 'dd' backup via lofi

Tags: solaris, ufs

I've got a 9G backup from a dead Solaris machine (SS20) that I'm trying to mount via lofi in Solaris.  It won't mount the entire image file and I'm not sure how to discover the partition layout so as to split it again with dd.

Am I better off just finding an appropriate sized thumb drive and going that route?

Comment: is the backup a dump of a partition or of an entire disk?

Answer (score 1):

Are you currently running Solaris on a SPARC machine or an x86 based one ? In the latter case, there is no way to mount the filesystem on it as the format is architecture dependant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Solaris, but with Linux there's a `-o loop` option. Could you try that and see if it works? If it doesn't, then edit your question and tell us what error message it's giving.

Comment: # mount -F ufs /dev/lofi/1 /mnt
mount: /dev/lofi/1 is not this fstype

(In the console I also get the message 'mount: not a UFS magic number (0x65722e20) )

Comment: After hassling with some oddities (mboot not installed, fdisk wants 'rlofi' and not 'lofi'), here's what I've got from fdisk:
`code`
# fdisk -G /dev/rlofi/1
* Physical geometry for device /dev/rlofi/1
* PCYL     NCYL     ACYL     BCYL     NHEAD NSECT SECSIZ
  29482    29482    0        0        1     600   512
`code`

Comment: You're on the right track, but see jilliagre's comment below.  This will have to be mounted on a SPARC system.